# iOS – Localized JSON resource

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, localization

I have a JSON resource resource.json in my /MyApp/Resources/ folder. I want this resource localized so I have chosen in Xcode to localize it for swedish and english. I now have 2 folders:

**/MyApp/Resources/sv.lproj/resource.json**

And

**/MyApp/Resources/en.lproj/resource.json**

So far so good. But whenever I try to use this resource with:

```
NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"resource" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

`jsonString` will always contain the english version of the resource. I have tried switching languages in both simulator and on device to no avail.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deletion of the app, clean and build it worked.